# Populate UITableView Sections table with Single NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, uitableview

Sorry to ask again the question with full description.What i have that i have resultsArray which has title description etc which gets from server but problem is that i want to show this data in sections.

So lets say if have three sections which are coming from array then how will populate the data in each section using single resultArray.

```
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
return [categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

resutArray has all the data for all sections so how to show according to sections

Structure of array is

```
             ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
            [theObject setCategory:[dict objectForKey:@"category"]];
            [theObject setSub_Category:[dict objectForKey:@"sub_Category"]];    
            [theObject setContent_Type:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Type"]];
            [theObject setContent_Title:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Title"]];
            [theObject setPublisher:[dict objectForKey:@"publisher"]];
            [theObject setContent_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Description"]];
    [theObject setContent_ID:[dict objectForKey:@"content_ID"]];
    [theObject setContent_Source:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Source"]];
        [resultArray addObject:theObject];
```

Comment: will you please show the structure of your array, what data are you storing in it. and on which item you want to show in section.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara i have added the structure of the array

Comment: Show your code then easy to solve..Thansk

Comment: you can calculate number of objects in row, then go on to start from next one. Is this so difficult?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i did not understand can you explain more

Comment: @Prem i have edited code please have a look.

Comment: For Each section you want to display all the above data right ?@ShahzedAli

Comment: for each section i want to show data which only for that sections i mean if there is section one values from array containg heder title of section one will be displayed

Comment: what about your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate??

Comment: thanks for your question buddy. I got my answer .

Answer (score 2):

Look's like you have ObjectData which has attribute called category, and you want to show table view with ObjectData's grouped by categories.
You may do this generating an NSDictionary with key = unique category, and value = NSArray of ObjectData of that category. Then you use that NSDictionary as a data for datacource.

```
NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/catalogMaster.php"];
// dictionary for cells, you'll probably want this to be ivar or property
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
// array for headers, you'll probably want this to be ivar or property
NSMutableArray* categories = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

    id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
    [theObject setCategory:[dict objectForKey:@"category"]];
    [theObject setSub_Category:[dict objectForKey:@"sub_Category"]];
    [theObject setContent_Type:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Type"]];
    [theObject setContent_Title:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Title"]];
    [theObject setPublisher:[dict objectForKey:@"publisher"]];
    [theObject setContent_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Description"]];
    [theObject setContent_ID:[dict objectForKey:@"content_ID"]];
    [theObject setContent_Source:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Source"]];


    [resultArray addObject:theObject];
    [theObject release];
    theObject=nil;

    // here you populate that dictionary and categories array
    NSMutableArray* objs = [dictionary objectForKey:theObject.category];
    if(!objs)
    {
        objs = [NSMutableArray array];
        [dictionary setObject:objs forKey:theObject.category];
        [categories addObject:theObject.category];
    }
    [objs addObject:theObject];
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [categories count] ;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

      return [categories objectAtIndex:section];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString* category = [categories objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray* objs = [dictionary objectForKey:category];
    ObjectData* obj = [objs objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    // populate cell here

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString* category = [categories objectAtIndex:section];
    NSMutableArray* objs = [dictionary objectForKey:category];
    return [objs count];
}
```

Note that that's just an example for you, you may optimize this as you want.

Comment: yes you are right i want like this can you please add some code if you can how to add like these

Comment: instead of categoires i think we have to give resultArray in which result is fetched from json

Comment: it is giving error index.path undeclared in numberofRowsInSection

Comment: Just a typo, fixed. I'm writing code here in web interface, so it's possible to meet some typos and small errors here.

Answer (score 1):

Using custom class you can achieve this.

**myClass.h**

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString* sectionHeader;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* sectionRows;
@end
```

**myClass.m**

```
#import "myClass.h"

@implementation myClass
@synthesize sectionHeader;
@synthesize sectionRows;
@end
```

First you need to set up your resultArray with above class object. Set Appropriate value for class. Example:

```
myClass *myClassObj = [[myClass alloc] init];
myClassObj.sectionHeader = @"Your section title";
myClassObj.sectionRows   = < Your NSMutableArray for rows under current section >;
[retunArray addObject:myClassObj];
```

Now Set `numberOfSectionsInTableView` , `numberOfRowsInSection`, `titleForHeaderInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [returnArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[returnArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    myClass *myClassObject = [returnArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return myClassObject.sectionHeader;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    myClass *myClassObject = [returnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%@",[myClassObject.sectionRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but how will it separte each sections for data for differnet title

Comment: you are right lets say i have title sections in array and the resultArray contains all the data how it will separate data for each sections from resultArray

Comment: see my resultArray as i told and categoryArray which is the sections array title

Comment: Your returnArray has all the data for all sections right. now you need to set object say of type NSMutableArray to your ObjectData class. and you can access that array and value as shown above

Comment: what to give myClassObje.sectionTitle=@"Your Section Title" this comes mine from categoryArray

Comment: Try to understand mechanism given above and set up your returnArray with ObjectClass. Set one property for sectionTitle inside your ObectClass and use that

Comment: I am did not getting your mechanism sectionRows and titles you are using from same array

Comment: you have mentioned your array for current sections it mean i have to make three arrays if i have 3 sections

Comment: See i have shown example for configuring array in that you will be having something like myClassObj.sectionRows here sectionRows is array for section

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is an NSMutableArray and you want to split it into sections means you have to know index of objects. 
For example,

```
[
Section 1,
Section1,
Section1,
Section 2,
Section 2,
Section2,
Section 3,
Section 3,
Section 3
]
```

in 1st sections display data from 0 to 2 index, in 2nd from 3 to 5 index, in 3rd from 6 to 8 index.

Else better go for `NSDictionary`. Keep section title as key and the values as NSArray in Dictionary. So it will be easier to load the cell.

You have NSArray Of Object Data.. So  you can do it as

```
    NSMutableDictionary *sectionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i < [data count]; i++)
    {
ObjectData *theObject = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        NSMutableArray *arr;
        if([sectionDict valueForKey:theObject.category])
        {
            arr = [sectionDict valueForKey:theObject.category];
        }
        else
        {
            arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [arr addObject:theObject];
        [sectionDict setObject:arr forKey:theObject.category];
    }
```

So now you will have required data...

Comment: yes section title will be best to make key and load data any e.g how to do this please

Comment: See updated answer.. You have split the data based on indexes and should have separate key for all sections...

Comment: i did not get this can you add my code as i have made more clear please

Answer (score 0):

Do same as in the sample code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [sectionArray count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: i do not know the exact number of section some time it may be 10 some time more that that or less that 10 becuase array is coming from server

Answer (score 0):

You might also find it much easier to use the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework will simply take your array and generate all the table view cells and sections, including all the detail views if you wish. I find it much simpler and literally takes a few minutes to implement.